# How to remove the white background from this icon?

Tags: graphics, icons, png, transparent

I have this icon.

[image]

There are some white background around the icon. I would like to remove this white background and make it transparent. How can this be done with a free software tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good programm I would use is GIMP. It's free and similar to photoshop.

You can download it here: [GIMP download](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

Also here is a YouTube video that might help you:
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC5vdKuwTp0)

Here a link to the program that was useful to user768421:
[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/)

Comment: May I ask how to use gimp to convert the white background to transparent? Sorry, I have never used gimp before.

Comment: I just added a YouTube link to a tutorial.

Comment: It would be nice if you mark my Answer as "Worked for me" if it helped you.

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting for more answers. Anyway, since you requested, it has been marked as the correct answer.

Comment: But were you eable to remove the white background?

Comment: I used another method. I used IfranView.

Comment: Good, I'm gonna add that to my awnser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is easiest background remover online and free - [Remove White Background Online](http://editphotosforfree.com/photoapps/remove-background-from-image-online/)